# Spring bean for an interface or how to tell that generic is going to have a method

Tags: hibernate, jpa, inheritance, interface

So I have this nice idea of having a generic class which must make a call to a  T.getId(), where T is an Entity, but java don't care what T is and that it's even a class so I need to tell it somehow.

My working class looks like this:

```
 @Service
 public class EGS<T extends Exe> extends BaseService {

      private T t;
      private XDao<T> genericDao; 
      ...

      public EmailGeneratorService(T t) {
           this.t = t;
      }

      public Entity get() {
           return this.t;
      }


      public void doStuff() {
           T t = genericDao.getById(this.t.getId());
           logger.debug(t.toString());
      }     
 }
```

and my interface looks like

```
 public interface Exe {
      Long getId();
      String toString();
 }
```

now java is ok with that, but "no qualifying bean of type [....Exe] found for dependency [?]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}"

So I kinna confused what I should do with all of it, and how can I tell java that my T is going to be an Entity and that every entity in my Spring MVC has a getId() method

Comment: Instantiate the bean yourself in a config class using `@Bean` instead of implicitly using `@Service`, then you can specify the `T` yourself. I suspect there's another way to do it, but this would be my first guess with my somewhat limited spring knowledge.

Comment: don't think it makes sense. the interface is located in the package scanned by  LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean like the rest of the Entities I have.